# float(export_entry.get()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to show in the GUI (as a label or as a message) specific rows from an excel file. In this case, the user will enter the week that he want to see. [In this case 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuX64.png). But i get the error     F = float(export_entry.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
(i know i have libraries that i dont use but at this point can stay there)
(i am using the code to enter the data in excel but that part is working fine)

This is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import date, datetime
from tkinter import *
from warnings import simplefilter
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
import xlrd
simplefilter("ignore")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Productie"]
week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")

class WritableStringVar(tk.StringVar):
    def write(self, added_text):
        new_text = self.get() + added_text
        self.set(new_text)

    def clear(self):
        self.set("")
def hello():
    wb_sales = pd.ExcelFile("excel.xlsx")
    #sheet_1 = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", sheet_name= 0)
    #sheet_2 = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", sheet_name= 1)
    sheet_3 = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", sheet_name= 2)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
    read_sheets_name = wb_sales.sheet_names
    F = float(export_entry.get())
    C =(sheet_3.query('["F"] in Week'))
    export_entry["text"]=str(C)


def write_to_xlsx():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
    sheet = wb["Productie"]
    week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    ws = wb.active
    maxim = ws.max_row + 1

    for i in range(8):
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=i+1, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=i+1)  # A

    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=24, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=24)  # X
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=25, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=25)  # Y
    week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    ws.cell(column=1, row=maxim, value=week_number)

    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime('%d/%m')
    ws.cell(column=2, row=maxim, value=dt_string)

    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list):
        ws.cell(column=ndex+3, row=maxim, value=entry_list[ndex].get())
        entry_list[ndex].delete(0, 'end')

    rows = range(1, maxim + 1)
    columns = range(1, 8)
    for row in rows:
        for col in columns:
            sheet.cell(row, col).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

    wb.save("excel.xlsx")


label_list = ['Model', 'Etapa', 'Batch', 'Cantitate', 'S/N']
entry_list = []

for i in range(len(label_list)):
    tk.Label(root, text=label_list[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w', padx=15)
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(root, width=20))
    entry_list[-1].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w', padx=15)

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=write_to_xlsx).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10)
tk.Button(root, text='Export', command=hello).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10)
week_label =tk.Label(root,text="week:").grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10)
export_label =tk.Label(root)
export_entry = tk.Entry(root).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, can you pare the code down to a *self-contained* example that doesn't require anything external like an Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you import or define 'export_entry'.

Normally when I have AttributeError:NoneType error messages it means that my variable is not defined. This is why the script can't execute 'get()'.

In this case I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: export_entry = tk.Entry(root).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='e', padx=10)